# Configure SQL Server 2012 to receive HTTP POST data

Tags: sql-server, post, http-post, sql-server-2012

### Intro

I designed a SurveyGizmo questionnaire for a client. When a respondent completes a questionnaire, I manually export a CSV file then load into Excel or a SQL Server development database to prototype reports. This is inefficient, especially as this could reach 100s of respondents when it is fully launched!

SurveyGizmo inform me that I can setup a HTTP CONNECT action that will send respondent data directly to SQL Server 2012 via HTTP GET or HTTP POST. **However, I will need to configure SQL Server 2012 to enable this.**

### Questions

- How will I go about setting up SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition to listen to HTTP POST requests, receive and populate a staging table in a database?

Answer (score 0):

I think this feature is deprecated in Sql 2012 and replaced by WCF

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707789%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: thanks for the quick response. My SQL Server experience is purely as a BI Developer - writing sql, doing analysis and reports! Any further assistance or clarification? How does WCF allow me to connect receive HTTP POST and populate and SQL Server 2012 Database?

Comment: It would take more than a simple comment to explain! WCF is a world it self! Basically, you expose an endpoint as a WCF Service, receive the data an create code to insert in your DDBB.

Comment: Just to confirm, this is the ONLY way of achieving this goal? How would I have acheived the above goal in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: As I said before, Microsoft deprecated SOAP/HTTP endpoints in SQL Server 2012 and these features are scheduled to be removed in a future release of SQL Server. Deprecated features should not be used in new applications. WCF is not the only way of doing it, it's the Microsoft replacement for deprecated features, butou can receive an HTTP POST and insert data in your DDBB using any webserver capable language like PHP, ASP, Ruby, C, Asp.Net or whichever is supported by your webserver.